# how to install fastai on windows 10

Tags: pip, conda

I cant seem to install the right version of torch and I cant get fast ai libraries working

I try

## Python 3.7

```
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
pip3 install torchvision
```

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.1.0 (from torchvision) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
No matching distribution found for torch>=1.1.0 (from torchvision)
```

I feel like I may of downgraded my gpu when I tried conda install fast ai

and then I tried pip and it couldnt find a file `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\caffe2\python\serialized_test\data\operator_test`

I finally got to the point where it said successfully installed six, pillow, and torch but torch is at 0.3 which is incompatiable.

```
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
pip3 install torchvision
```

expected to install pytorch or fastai nothing seems to work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try installing the course by creating a conda environment provided anaconda is already installed in your windows machine.

```
conda update conda    
conda create -n fastai_conda python=3.6
conda activate fastai_conda
conda install fastai pytorch=1.0.0 -c fastai -c pytorch -c conda-forge
```

Or for installing CPU version you can use the below commands after the environment is created

```
conda install -c pytorch pytorch-cpu torchvision
conda install -c fastai fastai
```

You can check if installation went right with this command

```
python -m fastai.utils.show_install
```

You may further need to install ipykernel to use the conda environment in your jupyter notebook.For that activate environment and run the following commands:

```
conda install nb_conda_kernels
python -m ipykernel install --user --name fastai_v1 --display-name "fastai v1"
conda install ipywidgets
```

Comment: @BenjiRevolutions Please don't add "thank you" as an answer or comment. Instead, [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that you found most helpful.